# Question about characterization of open sets in R

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Show that $A\subset \mathbf{R}$ is an open set if and only if it has the following property:
"If a sequence $(x_n)$ converges to $a \in A$ then $x_n \in A$ for all sufficiently large $n$"

My attempt:
The forward pass is very easy. I'm having trouble with the other one since I'm not even convinced that it's true. The statment is saying that if I give an $\epsilon$ region around a, it has all $x_n$ for all sufficiently large $n$, but that does not mean that all the points in that $\epsilon$ region are in $A$, so I can't find a $\epsilon$ region contained in $A$

Comment: If you're not convinced something is true, try to find a counterexample. If it actually is true, this helps you understand why it must be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, you want to prove that if every sequence $(x_n)$ which converges to some $a\in A$ has the property that there is some $n_0$ such that for all $n\geq n_0$, $x_n\in A$, then $A$ is open.

Assume, for contradiction that $A$ is not open. By definition, this means that there exists some $a\in A$, such that $B(a,r)\cap (\mathbb{R}\setminus A) \not= \emptyset$ for every $r>0$. Here $B(a,r)$ is the open ball around $a$ of radius $r$, that is $B(a,r)=(a-r,a+r)$. So, for each $n\in \mathbb{N}$, there exists some $x_n\in B(a,\frac{1}{n})\cap (\mathbb{R}\setminus A)$. Now, by definition, $x_n$ converges to $a$. However, also by definition, $x_n \not\in A$ for every $n$. Therefore it is not true that there is some $n_0$ such that for all $n\geq n_0$, $x_n\in A$. That is a contradiction.